# On Riemann integral

Tags: measure-theory, riemann-integration

Let $\{q_n\}_n$ an enumeration of rationals of $[0,1]$. We consider 
\begin{equation}
A=\bigcup_{n=1}^{+\infty}\bigg(q_n-\frac{1}{2^{n+2}},q_n+\frac{1}{2^{n+2}}\bigg).
\end{equation}
We can prove that $\chi_A$ is not Riemann integrable which is equivalent to prove that $A$ is not Peano-Jordan measurable.

Could you give me some hint on how to prove this?

**solution proposal**. Let $D=\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]$, then $D\subseteq A\subseteq [0,1]$. Now, $1=\overline{m}(D)\le\overline m(A)\le1$, then $\overline{m}(A)=1$. 
How can I do for inner measure?

**solution proposal 2**. 
\begin{equation}
\partial A\subseteq\bigcup_n\bigg(\partial\bigg(q_n-\frac{1}{2^{n+2}},q_n+\frac{1}{2^{n+2}}\bigg)\bigg)=[0,1],
\end{equation}
then 
\begin{equation}
[0,1]=\partial D\subseteq\partial A\subseteq [0,1]
\end{equation}
therefore $m(\partial A)=1$, then $A$ is not Peano-Jordan measurable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that every point $x \in [0,1]\setminus A$ is a point of discontinuity of $\chi_A$: take rationals $q_n \to x$ and just observe that $\chi_A(q_n) = 1$ for each $n$ while $\chi_A(x) = 0$. So the set of points of discontinuity of $\chi_A$ has Lebesgue measure at least that of $[0,1]\setminus A$, which is positive, since the Lebesgue measure of $A$ is at most $\frac{1}{2}$. We conclude that $\chi_A$ is not Riemann Integrable.